# show activity stream google plus with next page pagination

Tags: php, google-plus

how to make next page button , to show activity stream

```
$client = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/' . $uid . '/activities/public?key='.$key . '&orderBy=recent&maxResults=100&fields=nextPageToken,items'));
```

work for 99 result . but not show next page to 100 more resuls.

how to make next page link for show 100 more results.

Answer (score 0):

You take the value of `nextPageToken` from the response and add it as `pageToken` to the URL query params for the next request.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/' . $uid . '/activities/public?key=...&pageToken=' . $nextPageToken
```